# c# data reader change field name before Binding

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, bindingsource

I have `SqlDataReader` that fill with `ExecuteDataReader` statement.
I want to change some column name  in DataReader after fill.

for example after fill datareader i have two column (A,B)
i want to change colum `'A'` to `'a'`(convert to lowercase)befor binde to grid

```
sqlDataReader reader;
reader.executedatareadet();
```

like `reader.GetName(i)`
i want to be abe somthing like

```
reader.SetName(i)
```

but it seams that we cant change the datareader column name

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Can you specify "i want to change some column name"? It might help to see what you have tried.

Comment: Please post a specific question. A post that is nothing more than "I want to do something" might be proper at some discussion forums, but is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataReader` is only for reading the returned data. You read the values and you put them in your own data structures or variables.

The only way to change the structure of the data reader is on the data origin, i.e. the SQL query which formats the returned data.

Comment: alex tahnk you for youre reponse .you mean it is not possible to change the column name in datareader after fill and befor bindig to grid..?

Comment: You should use a [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx). You may call the `Fill(DataTable)` or `Fill(DataSet)` methods to populate a `DataTable` object. Then, you bind it to the grid's data source.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the data in your own variable then. Run your executeReader() and put the result in a var dataHolder.
Then loop through the dataHolder with a

```
   foreach(var x in dataHolder)
   {
        x.Property = x.Property.ToLower(); //Or something like this
   }
```

Then when you're finished, you can put the dataHolder in a grid or something

Comment: thanks 'Mikey' but for large DataSet it is too time consumming to put reasult to another dataholer.i don't want to copy data to another dataholder.it has overhead

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize you were dealing with a very large dataset. You could try a Linq2Sql approach that would let you pull the data directly into a container with Properties that you can update, I think you can even do the "toLower" stuff directly on the Database side with Linq2Sql

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a middle model layer between the reading and binding. After you read the data from data reader, load the data into your intermediate model and then make changes to the data there and then bind your model collection to the datasource.